# How do we know that Dark Energy has homogeneous energy density?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, redshift

I’ve read places that the density of Dark Energy is the same throughout the universe.

- If the expansion density of dark energy were the same throughout the universe, why don’t all galaxies have the same recession velocity (or do they)?
- Is it possible that a red-shift can change based on proximity to a galaxy?
- If so, would this have implications for the density of dark energy?